How to export a model (from e.g., Blender) to a finite difference grid?
Hoping we can get some help on this. We want to do electromagnetic simulations and need a regular finite difference mesh to do so. We want to be able to export a model (from e.g., Blender) to a finite difference grid and specify the start, stop, and step of each x, y, and z axis.
We tried this with Blender using the re-mesh > blocks modifier. It looks promising, but it does not yield a dense mesh as needed for EM simulations.
We are open to paying for tools, but the ~$15k cost of the big names (Altair, etc.) are out of our reach at the moment.
Thank you in advance for any help or insights!

Assuming a model from blender comes represented as an unstructured mesh, what exactly is your goal to produce from it as it relates to a structure finite difference grid? Do you have an example you can use to illustrate what you are hoping to achieve?
